# Undefined reference to mosquitto_lib_init

Tags: c, mqtt, mosquitto

Problem

- Undefined reference to mosquitto_lib_init and some others C functions, generating this error:

  gcc  -o "Protheus"  ./src/Brain/Brain.o ./src/Brain/Network.o
  ./src/Brain/Network.o: In function `mqtt_init_server':
  Network.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to`mosquitto_new'
  Network.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `mosquitto_connect'
  Network.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to`mosquitto_lib_init'
  makefile:30: recipe for target 'Protheus' failed
  Network.c:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `mosquitto_subscribe'
  Network.c:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to`mosquitto_message_callback_set'
  Network.c:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `mosquitto_loop_forever'
  Network.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to`mosquitto_destroy'
  Network.c:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_cleanup'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [Protheus] Error 1
- I've tried run the code using mosquitto.h, but I can't get compiling that source.
- When I try run the code my makefile it's broke.

[MAKEFILE]

```
    -include ../makefile.init

    RM := rm -rf

    # All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
    -include sources.mk
    -include src/Brain/subdir.mk
    -include subdir.mk
    -include objects.mk

    ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
    -include $(C_DEPS)
    endif
    endif

    -include ../makefile.defs

    # Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

    # All Target
    all: Protheus

    # Tool invocations
    Protheus: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
        @echo 'Building target: $@'
        @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Linker'
        gcc  -o "Protheus" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
        @echo ' '

    # Other Targets
    clean:
        -$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS) Protheus
        -@echo ' '

    .PHONY: all clean dependents
    .SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

==================================================================

- My code is :

  ```
  int ip_address(){
      int fd;
      struct ifreq ifr;
      char iface[] = "eth0";
      fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);


      ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;


      strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
      ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
      close(fd);


      IFACE = iface;
      IP_ADDRESS = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) &ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);
      if (IP_ADDRESS != NULL && strlen(IP_ADDRESS) > 7) {

      return 1;
      }

  return 0;    }
  ```

  int check_connection(){

  ```
     if (ip_address()){


          return 0;
      }

  return 1;}
  ```

  void my_message_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *message){

  printf ("Got message: %s\n", (char *)message->payload);

}

```
int mqtt_init_server(){
    MOSQUITTO *mosq = NULL;
    mosq    = mosquitto_new(NULL,0,NULL);
    int ret = mosquitto_connect(mosq, MQTT_HOSTNAME,MQTT_PORT,0);

    if (0 == ret || !mosquitto_lib_init() || !mosq)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Can't initialize Mosquitto library\n");
            return 0;
        }

    ret = mosquitto_subscribe(mosq,NULL,MQTT_TOPIC,0);
    if(ret)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Can't publish to Mosquitto server\n");
            return 0;
        }

    mosquitto_message_callback_set (mosq, my_message_callback);
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq,-1,1);
    mosquitto_destroy (mosq);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();

    return 1;
    printf("CONECTED");
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: `undefined reference` is a link error.  You are not linking with the library that contains that code.